# Finding a change of basis matrix given S and T

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0sBF.png)

I've stuck in this problem for a couple of hours. I've found examples on the Internet, but it seems to me that the problem I'm dealing with doesn't provide all the information I need. Am I right or there does exist a way to solve it?

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Let S = (v1; v2) and T = (w1; w2) be basis for R2, where
v1 = (1, 2) ; v2 = (0, 1) ; w1 = ( 1, 1)  ; w2 = ( 2, 3)
Compute the change of basis matrix from T to S.

Comment: You have to write $w_1 = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2$, then do the same for $w_2$ and the coefficents will be the coefficents of your transformation matrix.

Comment: The change of basis matrix is a matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(v_1,v_2)=(w_1,w_2)A$. This boils down to expressing $v_1$ and $v_2$ linearly in terms of $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Comment: You are trying to find $P_{T}^{S}$, so express this as an augmented matrix where the LHS are you basis vectors from $S$ as columns and the RHS are your basis vectors from $T$ as columns. Then row reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the desired matrix such that 
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}M_{1,1}&M_{1,2}\\M_{2,1}&M_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $M_{1,1},M_{1,2},M_{2,1}$ and $M_{2,2}$ are constants to be determined. From the problem statement that you provided we are aware what the images of the basis vectors of $T$ are under this Linear Tranformation or (Change of Basis) consequently
$$\begin{pmatrix}M_{1,1}&M_{1,2}\\M_{2,1}&M_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$
and 
$$\begin{pmatrix}M_{1,1}&M_{1,2}\\M_{2,1}&M_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ implies that $$\begin{pmatrix}M_{1,1}+M_{1,2}\\M_{2,1}+M_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$

similary $(2)$ implies that 
$$\begin{pmatrix}2M_{1,1}+3M_{1,2}\\2M_{2,1}+3M_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

Systems $(3)$ and $(4)$ yield the following equations
$$M_{1,1}+M_{1,2} = 1\\
2M_{1,1}+3M_{1,2}   = 0$$

and 
$$M_{2,1}+M_{2,2} = 2\\
2M_{2,1}+3M_{2,2}   = 1$$

solving the above system of equations will yield
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\5&-3\end{pmatrix}$$

I suggest you compute the images of the basis vectors of $T$ using $M$ just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Given $S=\{[1,2]^t,[0,1]^t\}$ and $T=\{[1,1]^t,[2,3]^t\}$ we want to find the change-of-basis matrix $P$ from $T$ to $S$.

Using matrices:

$[S|T]\rightarrow[I_2|P]$ by elementary row operations.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
      1&   0&   1&  2\\
      2&   1&   1&  3\\
    \end{array}\right]$$

Then $R_2=-2R_1+R_2$

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
      1&   0&   1&  2\\
      0&   1&  -1&  -1\\
    \end{array}\right]$$

Where $P=$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
      1&   2\\
      -1&   -1\\
    \end{array}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a change of basis question, you take the matrix and flip it from S to T (originally it stated from T to S)in order to solve for the identity matrix. So in this case set up the matrix in the way I described above and use row reduction to get the left matrix equal to the identity matrix. Can you please set up both matrixes and show me what you got?